# Drawing polygons on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas, google-maps-api-3

I was drawing polygons using  [Polygon Creator Class](http://www.the-di-lab.com/polygon/)  on Google Maps. As you see this tool is not easy to use. For example, it's impossible to add new polygon or edit some of them after getting result code.

In following link when you zoom in between polygons you will see gaps that I want to remove. To recreate the issue please open following link and zoom in between polygons:

http://jsbin.com/bovogaqowu/1/edit?js,output

Now question is, how to remove gap between these polygons ? In this case I can't use the tool that I  used to create this map.

And which tool is better to use in this situation ?

Thank for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you using the Google's official tool for drawing, editing, locatiing and even finding driving directions for the markers you have placed on the maps. You can always save these edited maps and retrieve them later when you need them.

Please click the following [link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) and get started!!

Even I tried drawing some polygons side by side and there were no gaps :)

Hope this would help!!